# Passing a structure with shared memory

Tags: c, struct, posix, shared-memory

Hi I want to pass my structure from father to son in `C` (not `c#` or `c++`).
My problem is to do parsing data in shared memory and out share memory , I must to do this i can't use `FIFO` or other system

you can assume struct `operazione`  and I use an array of this `operazione structure[number]`

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char operatore[1];
    int operandoprimo;
    int operandosecondo;
    int risultato;
    int risultato;
    int semid;
} operazione;
```

sorry some comments are in italian but you can understand easily .

father:

```
 /* CREO ZONA DI MEMORIA */
   int shmid = cMemC(KEY_MEMORIA,righeoperazioni*(sizeof(operazione)),IPC_CREAT|0666);    
    // 

         // attacco memoria condivisa
          shm =attacMemC(shmid,NULL,0);

          s = shm;

          for(exa=0 ; exa<righeoperazioni ; exa++){

                sprintf(*s++,"%d",comandi[exa].id);
                sprintf(*s++,"%s",comandi[exa].operatore);
                sprintf(*s++,"%d",comandi[exa].operandoprimo);
                sprintf(*s++,"%d",comandi[exa].operandosecondo);
                sprintf(*s++,"%d",comandi[exa].risultato);
                sprintf(*s++,"%d",comandi[exa].semid);
                    }
           s=NULL;

    //
```

to son :

```
operazione comandif[righe];

/* CREO ZONA DI MEMORIA */
    int shmid = cMemC(KEY_MEMORIA,oper*(sizeof(operazione)),IPC_EXCL|0666);   
    // attacco memoria condivisa
    shmf =attacMemC(shmid,NULL,0);
    ss = shmf;
    exa=0;
    for(ss=0 ; ss != NULL ; ss++){
                            sprintf(temp,"%d",*ss);
                comandif[exa].id=atoi(temp);
                sprintf(temp,"%d",*ss);
                sprintf(comandif[exa].operatore,"%s",temp);
                sprintf(temp,"%d",*ss);
                comandif[exa].operandoprimo=atoi(temp);
                sprintf(temp,"%d",*ss);
                comandif[exa].operandosecondo=atoi(temp);
                sprintf(temp,"%d",*ss);
                comandif[exa].risultato=atoi(temp);
                sprintf(temp,"%d",*ss);
                comandif[exa].semid=atoi(temp);
                exa++;
           }
```

Comment: What is your question? Also this is not plain C. What does cMemC do?

Comment: cmemc is shmget function put in control code = -1 to catch error

Comment: what does shmget do? and what is your question?

Comment: SORRY FOR THIS .. cMemcC as attacMemc are functions as shmget and shmat but with =-1 return control .. no problem from this

Comment: sorry but you can read on terminal man shmget , create memory ... my question is up this text code and comments !

Comment: Don't use the `shmget` family of functions in new code if you don't have to. Use the newer and simpler `shm_open` and `mmap` functions, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop using `sprintf()` to 'write' to the shared memory is bogus.  What is the type of `s`?  Its declaration isn't shown, but it doesn't matter much.  If it is a `char **`, as it should be for its use, you are writing multi-digit numbers into 'single bytes' of memory (it's a bit more complex than that, but it bears no resemblance to copying the structure into shared memory as you should be doing).

You probably need:

```
operazione *target = (operazione *)shm;
memmove(target, commandi, righeoperazioni * sizeof(operazione));
```

This will give you copies of the `commandi` array of `operazione` structures in your shared memory.  You actually don't need the target variable; you could use just:

```
memmove(shm, commandi, righeoperazione * sizeof(operazione));
```

Comment: Given `char *s`, your `sprintf()` code should be generating compilation warnings all over the place, even for a brain-dead compiler.  Don't ignore compiler warnings — remember, at this stage in your programming career, the C compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.  In 10 years, you may be able to decide differently (but I wouldn't want to bet on it even so); until then, pay attention to your compiler.

Comment: As to 'what is `memmove()`?', the answer is 'a standard C function for moving memory around safely'.  There is also a function `memcpy()` which does roughly the same job, but not if the source and target areas of memory overlap, whereas `memmove()` always works even if the memory areas overlap.  There are those who will tell you to use `memcpy()` because it is faster.  It would probably be safe here since the memory holding `commandi` won't overlap the shared memory, but I prefer to make sure my code can't go wrong, so I use `memmove()` as a matter of policy.

Comment: and in son i ll use same memmove function to put out from shared memory in new struct ?

Comment: Correct, you can use `memmove()` to copy the data out of shared memory too.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i ll tried to create a better code than this :) i'm student and many road to do :) thanks